# How to delete text when it falls outside the plot area in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to write text on a plot, but I noticed that when I move the horizontal position using matplotlib's panning (P key + mouse dragging) and the text is out of the plot area, it still appears. I would like it to disappear once its position exceeds the limits of the x-axis.

Here is a picture to make myself clearer:

[image]

The annotation on the right shouldn't be there. It should be present only if the position of the annotation is inside the x-axis.

Here's my code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as np

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1), autoscale_on=False)
x,y = np.random.rand(2,200)
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.text(np.mean(x), np.max(y), 'A',
        rotation = 0,
        ha = 'center',
        fontsize = 15,
        bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow',edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round'))
show()
```

EDIT: Setting `clip_on=True` makes the annotation disappear, as it should be above the vertical axis maximum. On the following picture, the left shows what happens when that argument is set to `True`; on the right, the desired image.

[image]

Comment: Note that matplotlib has panning built in. Press the **p** key and drag the mouse around. `text`, like other artists, should have a `clip_on` argument, which, if set to `True`, would make the artist being clipped by the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The `clip_on` argument clips the artist by both axes. Is it possible to do it just for the horizontal one? See updated post to see what I mean.

Comment: The default clip path is the extent of the axes. But it should be possible to set a different clip path, which is the axes extent in horizontal and the figure extent in vertical direction. Alternatively one can register a callback which sets the visibility of the text, depending on its coordinates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't really know what you mean by 'path'. I'm kind of a newbie with matplotlib. Is there any place where I could read about this specific topic (clipping, apparently)?

Comment: It's admidedly not straight forward. Artists can have a clip path set via [`.set_clip_path`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_clip_path.html). [Here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_clip_path.html) would be an example. One would need to use a blended transform for the path though. I will not be able to give a complete answer today, but if you haven't found a solution and no-one else did provide an answer until then feel free to remind me tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `clip_on=True` the default clip path (i.e. the area which clips the artist) is the axes. Here, you want to clip by the axes extent only in x direction. In y direction you would want to clip by the figure extent. This is possible by using a custom clip path.

Such clip path can be a matplotlib patch, e.g. a `Rectangle`. Then, the rectangle may be defined in a blended coordinate system, such that it extends from 0 to 1 along the x direction in axes coordinates, and from 0 to 1 along the y direction in figure coordinates. Setting the clip path of the text to the hence defined rectangle allows the text to be clipped by the axes in x- and by the figure in y-direction.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1), autoscale_on=False)
x,y = np.random.rand(2,200)
ax.scatter(x,y)

trans = mtrans.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes, fig.transFigure)
clippath = plt.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, transform=trans, clip_on=False)

txt = ax.text(np.mean(x), np.max(y), 'A',
        rotation = 0,
        ha = 'center',
        fontsize = 15,
        bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow',edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round'),
        clip_on=True)
txt.set_clip_path(clippath)

plt.show()
```

[image]